# Background Image disapear when changing its url in JS

Tags: javascript, css, background-image

I'm trying to change my background image when I click on it, but the background image just disapear.
Even when I try to change it by the exact same image
[Before click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPcjw.jpg)
And when I click and start my replace function you can see that the new url is the exact same
[After click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4Zuk.jpg)

JS part

```
    tamponContent.style.backgroundImage = "url('../../svg/Items/ReceptionTampon.svg')";
```

Css part

```
    background-image: url("../../svg/Items/ReceptionTampon.svg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
```

Its not a queryselector error because I can see that it changes the url ( and i tried setting a background color and this worked )

Comment: Remove the single quotes from the inline style property.

Comment: your url should be absolute to a static root, this is a bad idea `../../`, it should be something like  `images/svg/Items/ReceptionTampon.svg.`, i'm not sure if use bundler, that's prolly why it resolves first image for you.

Comment: Try using different paths e.g. absolute path to the image like `/images/svg/Items/ReceptionTampon.svg`. Also, try using double quotes for the JS Image Url too: `tamponContent.style.backgroundImage = "url("../../svg/Items/ReceptionTampon.svg")";` - hopefully one of these should solve the issue as you said that its not a `querySelector` error. If it still doesn't work maybe try selecting the element using `getElementByID`

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way around it !
I just create a new class with just the new background image url, and then add or remove this class as will

CSS

```
.tampon--top {

position: absolute;
z-index: 20;

width: 10vw;
height: 10vw;

background-image: url("../../svg/Items/ReceptionTamponTop.svg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;

pointer-events: none;

}

.tampon--topInk {

background-image: url("../../svg/Items/ReceptionTamponTop_ink.svg");
```

JS

```
if(ink) {
    tamponInk = true;
    tamponTop.classList.add("tampon--topInk");
}else {
    tamponInk = false;
    tamponTop.classList.remove("tampon--topInk");
}
```